# How to collect my tests with py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I try to collect my tests with py.test but it doesn't do so.

- **Do I have to provide additional options at the command line?**
- Py.test was executed in the directory of my .py-file. **Are there any other requirements?**
- **Are my tests named correctly?** In my code I used 'Test-' for classes and 'test_' for methods.

### The results from the terminal:

```
> py.test

===============================  in 0.00 seconds ============================
user@host:~/workspace/my_project/src/html_extractor$ py.test

============================= test session starts ===========================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4
plugins: xdist
collected 0 items
```

### My code under test:

```
class Factories(object):
    TEST_LINKS = ['http://www.burgtheater.at',
                  'http://www.musikverein.at/']

    def links(self):
        for link in self.TEST_LINKS:
            yield link


class TestHTMLExtractor(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = Factories()
        self.extractor = HTMLExtractor()


    def test_extract_site_return(self):
        for link in self.factory.links():
             raw_html_page = self.extractor.run(link)

def test_whatever():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: redirecting outputs to file is not working?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the default configuration, the test file should be named `test_<something>.py`.  See [Changing standard (Python) test discovery](http://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-standard-python-test-discovery).